# Buying the Community Books to Generate Questions

Tags: discussion, questions

A little while back, Jeff Atwood made a [comment](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/962/has-role-playing-games-stack-exchange-lost-its-appeal/964#comment-2138) about how Gaming was seeding members of the community with new games to help encourage them to ask questions. I was initially skeptical of the idea, but having given it some thought I believe it's worth at least posting about. If for no other reason than to start getting some proactive and out-of-the-box ideas for generating new questions posted here.

The first potential issue this faces is simply finding good candidates for the program. Unlike video games, RPGs require a group of people to really play through. And unlike board games, they require a pretty hefty time commitment. I know I probably couldn't provide a very good ROI myself, and I'd imagine that many adult players are in my boat.

But I don't think that this is a show stopper. Surely there must be a few groups out there that would be interested in trying a new RPG every *N* months.

The next issue would be product selection. Even among publishers that are actively producing content, the new content is almost exclusively in the form of add-on products. Which are probably too niche individually to do anyone much good.

So we'd need some mechanism to select a game, and figure out the minimum number of books to get a good experience out of it (and possibly an exemplar published module). This would probably be a good way of focusing game-specific pushes (which I believe have been brought up in comments somewhere).

Are there some angles I'm missing here? Does anyone have any thoughts on Jeff's idea?

Answer (score 10):

It's a good idea, and I don't think it needs to be as complicated as all that.

Actually, multiple new games come out every month, they're just not D&D.  See new releases on [IPR](http://www.indiepressrevolution.com/xcart/home.php), [RPGNow](https://www.rpgnow.com/?), the [Paizo store](http://paizo.com/store), The back wall of my FLGS is "new stuff" and there's always a good 30 products.

And once you add in major rule sets worthy of questionage, it's even more. I personally am looking forward to, in the near future, Ultimate Combat and Ultimate Magic for Pathfinder (Paizo), Ashen Stars (Pelgrane), DCC RPG (Goodman), Lamentations of the Flame Princess (same)... Mongoose, Green Ronin, there's a lot of companies with multiple product a month release schedules just keeping it to new games and major expansions.

We don't get many questions about adventures, though I'm not really sure why not, seems like this would be a good venue for "How can I make Tomb of Horrors not suck" or similar. There are whole forums on paizo.com about the Adventure Paths and questions regarding them.

Minor splatbooks, like "Joe's Guide to Whatever," are probably niche enough not to merit this treatment.

I don't think the requirement would be "multiple books and an exemplar published module and run a campaign with it!"  The point is to generate questions and have someone knowledgeable enough to answer.  I think it would work like this.

1. Person gets a free game.  We target say 1 a month and pick out likely major new releases by preorder and buzz. We initially populate this queue with high rep users, like 5k+, who volunteer. Parcel them out by a combo of interest and rep.
2. That person commits to reading it and asking at least 3 (good) questions on it within a month of receipt. Furthermore, they are expected to at least try to answer any questions that come up on that game in the near future. Playtest/playing it is nice but not mandatory, with RPGs that's just unrealistic.
3. People that deliver to our satisfaction on #2 get put back in the queue. New 5k users get in too, unless we get so many that we need to up the rep buyin. This encourages rep whoring, I mean site participation.
4. Profit.

Comment: Sounds fun :) I'd try it.

Comment: Maybe this is what you intended in your response so apologies if it is, but I think to really work, it would need a group of people to choose to look over the same books in a roughly similar time period and produce a volume of questions between them as they learned the system. Too few a number of researchers will force too many people into having to answer their own questions and with newer or less-known games really limit the field of possible respondents.

Comment: @Runeslinger It's pretty rare that we don't have someone able to answer a question (even if we don't get a lot of questions asked on the topic). There's also the old trick of cross posting to the official forums, etc. But beyond all that, part of the point is to get some questions that need answers... So I don't think that's necessarily a problem.

Comment: @mxy IMO, some play-time should be the expected case. Not an epic campaign, but a night or two or the completion of a module. Perhaps I'm an outlier in this regard, but every system I've ever taught myself has gelled dramatically in the first couple of sessions of play... And we want a bit of quality control here.

Comment: @mxy I was also thinking that we'd get more questions from people learning an entire new game (Pathfinder, or Call of Cthulu, or what have you) than from people who knew a game getting an expansion (Ultimate Combat, Heroes of Shadow, etc.).

Comment: On a completely unrelated note... Are any of the adventure path questions suitable for porting over to this site?

Comment: I think this is a really promising idea, and I'd love to see the topic spread diversified by something like this.

Comment: There are about 100k people that know how to play existing games like PF and CoC.  We don't need to spend money on that, there is where we just need to attract the existing folks.  I think the value in this idea is specifically new games.

Comment: I don't necessarily think we need to give each game to multiple people - I mean, I guess that's fine depending on what kind of budget the SE team is looking at, but one would be sufficient.  It's enough to catalyze the other folks out there (currently on SE or not) to gel around it.  (If SE has unlimited money they can buy us all copies, I won't object)

Comment: And as for play required - of course we'd encourage play but requiring it is unrealistic. Most people don't have that many play opps a month, mostly taken by existing games. For good or ill, 90% of RPG purchases are never played, just read.

Comment: Sadly, true... My to be played list is getting ridiculously full, but cannot hold a candle to the number of titles in my library.

Comment: @Ace  Good point, unanswered questions are exactly what we want so that there are questions to answer when new people arrive. I wasn't thinking.

Comment: My point wasn't that those games, specifically, should be chosen. It was just an example of a base game to oppose expansion books. Re: selection, I think the existing audience isn't important (there's advantages to both mainstream and obscure games). The important thing is getting something as different as possible to the participants. So that'll depend on who's in.

Comment: I think a lot of the value is to cover *new* releases and *new* games, and having that novelty help drive traffic.  I am much less encouraged about an "give people copies of old games to seed questions."  I bet if you name any game there will be a number of people here that own it already. I own more than 1000 RPG books and supplements. I am not asking questions about them because a) I already know or b) I don't care.  This should be a new release program for sure.

Comment: @mxy Right, well, giving someone a book for a system they already own is right out because it isn't likely to result in new questions. That's what I've been saying this whole time. The difference between new old games and new new games is a tradeoff: The older games have a larger potential audience to gain, but a lot more competition for those eyeballs. New games will have a much smaller potential audience (unless they're a rare major release), but a good novelty factor.

Comment: I don't completely follow you.  I assume that e.g. Ultimate Combat would go to someone that already owns Pathfinder, whereas a brand new whole game would go to someone that doesn't have it... I assume you're not just saying "don't give a product to someone who already has it" which I assume goes without statement. Something like "a new version of Shadowrun" could profitably go to a total newbie or to someone who's really into the old edition of course, bringing basic and advanced questions to the table respectively.

Comment: @mxyzplk I'm saying that I don't think that expansion books like Ultimate Combat, Heroes of Shadow, the Vampire clanbooks, or the 7th Sea nation books are worth buying (unless they're part of an essential core).Someone who receives such a book already knows the system's rules engine, the setting, and the system philosophy. Like I said above: "Even among publishers that are actively producing content, the new content is almost exclusively in the form of add-on products. Which are probably too niche individually to do anyone much good." But that's just my opinion. I have no numbers to confirm it

Comment: Not all will be but we'll vet that.  We already have plenty of Pathfinder APG questions here.  If there is a forum somewhere with hundreds of threads on a specific product, then it's probably something to bring on topic here, seems like a reasonable statement.

Comment: @mxyzplk That sounds reasonable.

Comment: How about doing it as a promotion thing? If a company wants exposure for their product, they offer a free PDF to a couple users to ask questions and generate some buzz about the product. They can even send some company reps over here to answer questions.

Comment: @migo not really interested in that.  It will, frankly, get too much response.  As someone who blogs a lot I get inundated by people who are willing to give free PDFs for a review, and the price is still too high. I think to maintain quality and cover products someone might actually care about, a program like this makes sense to be "real print games only."  Having said that, if the publisher wants to foot the bill for something we've selected as a valuable thing to seed Q&A on, great.

Comment: If it's a print copy, the publisher really is footing the bill, whereas if it's a PDF copy of a product that's also in print, they're just saving us money. There's also the thing that books take up space. I'd rather just use something like the Kindle DX and not have to deal with extra books on my shelf, so PDF has a lot of extra practicality there too.

Comment: PD is a valid format, that's fine, just saying that a) games that are PDF only are unlikely to meet the noteworthiness level required for this and b) we should not do this as an open call for publisher donations; we should specifically solicit/procure games that we think will get volume on the site.

Comment: One minor issue I regularly have with new games in multiple editions is knowing which titles belong with with edition, and which 3rd party products match which edition, etc. When trying to get into a new system by picking up the pdfs on drivethru for example the lack of information is daunting. Working in concert with them to flesh out solid questions and answers about systems and settings here, and drive traffic back and forth via a banner exchange and Q&A links could accomplish a fair bit, could it not?